# How associate model server with stats in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models:

Model Server with columns `ip`, `port`, `players_online`, `votes`. 
And I have model Stats with columns: `server_id`, `online`, `votes`.

In stats model I have:

```
protected $fillable = ['server_id', 'votes', 'online'];

public function server() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Server');
}
```

I have code:

```
    $servers = Server::all();
    foreach($servers as $server) {
        $statss = getMcServer($server->ip, $server->port);
        $server->players_online = $statss['online'] ? $statss['online'] : 0;

        $stats = new Stats();
        $stats->server()->associate($server);
        $stats->save();

        $server->save();
    }
```

When I use associate, I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'online' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `stats` (`server_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (24, 2018-05-15 12:12:21, 2018-05-15 12:12:21))
```

Comment: Yes. Do: `$stats->server()->associate($server); $stats->save();`. Where's your problem?

Comment: But columns `online` and `players_online` different, no?

Comment: What? Explain your problem.

Comment: Dates from $server do not fill to stats.. Because columns is different..

Comment: @Troyer see please updated question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this should work:

```
$servers = Server::all();
foreach($servers as $server) {
    $statss = getMcServer($server->ip, $server->port);
    $server->players_online = $statss['online'] ? $statss['online'] : 0;

    $stats = new Stats();
    $stats->online = $server->players_online;
    $stats->votes = $server->votes;
    $stats->server()->associate($server);

    $stats->save();

    $server->save();
}
```

Looking at your error looks like the field `online` from stats model is set as `guarded` or not set as `fillable`, you should add it in the `fillable` array of the model, so you can set the data and then save it to the database:

```
protected $fillable = ['votes','online'];
```

You can read more about `fillable` and `guarded`  in the [Eloquent -> Inserting & Updating Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) from Laravel official docs.

In case your `fillable` array is fine, probably the columns of your database are not nullable or doesn't have a default value, if this data is not mandatory or is optional, change them to nullabe or add a default value and the problem is going to be solved.

Comment: I have $fillable in model stats

Comment: Fields online, votes not nullable.. But need pass data from players_online and votes from model server..

Comment: I set this columns nullabe.. Error I don't show. But in stats table I see only server_id filled. But other columns is null..